# What deskew value to use for ImageMagick convert for a counterclockwise deskew of 5 degrees?

Tags: jpeg, imagemagick-convert

I need a counter-clockwise deskew of 5 degrees on a jpg image. I want to do this with the program `convert` of the ImageMagick tool suite. I thus need a command like:

```
convert '2 skewed jpg/p. 2.jpg' -deskew ???% '3 deskewed jpg/p. 2.jpg'
```

The question is what value should be filled in for `???`?
I tried already many things, and nothing works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I condensed your question a little bit so that it is easier to read and also formatted the code.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, -deskew is an automatic process to square up the image. It typically works for skewed images of about 5 deg or less. You can try 40% as a start and increase if it does not work.

But I think you want -shear, which does a controlled skew or shear with degree argument values. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#shear. For a horizontal shear top left by 5 deg, try

```
convert input.jpg -background white -shear -5x0 result.jpg
```

Input:

[image]

```
convert lena.jpg -background white -shear -5x0 result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Came here via queue and learned some ImageMagick. Thank you for that :)